# convert list's hyperlink to image base 64 string by using canvas

Tags: jquery, list, canvas, asynchronous, base64

i am new for jquery mobile.Inside my list's consist hyperlink . I need to convert **href**  to base 64 string . Please see my code below

html

```
 <div id="nPhoto" style="max-height: 600px; display: none;">

                <div class="thumbs" id="thumbs">



                     <a href="http://i0.gmx.net/images/258/18821258,pd=2,h=250,mxh=600,mxw=800,w=480.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://i0.gmx.net/images/258/18821258,pd=2,h=250,mxh=600,mxw=800,w=480.jpg)" title="1234" data-name="newImage" ></a>
                    <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7042/6895252645_45f5dfffaa_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7042/6895252645_45f5dfffaa_m.jpg)" title="1234" data-name="newImage"></a>
                    <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7183/6943277737_21b521659c_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7183/6943277737_21b521659c_m.jpg)" title="1234" data-name="newImage"></a>
                    <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7047/7000951429_5eae078a62_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7047/7000951429_5eae078a62_m.jpg)" title="1234" data-name="newImage"></a>
                    <a href="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5346/7051537899_efc7a44830_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5346/7051537899_efc7a44830_m.jpg)" title="1234" data-name="newImage"> </a>
                    <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7268/6951148260_440661b4d1_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7268/6951148260_440661b4d1_m.jpg)" title="1234" data-name="newImage"></a>
                    <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7259/6930112984_5fcc076288_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7259/6930112984_5fcc076288_m.jpg)" title="1234" data-name="newImage"></a>
                    <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7276/6886626710_047cd03acb_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7276/6886626710_047cd03acb_m.jpg)" title="1234" data-name="newImage"></a>
                    <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7020/6683299491_f2b5f6aa8b_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7020/6683299491_f2b5f6aa8b_m.jpg)" title="1234" data-name="newImage"></a>

                </div>
```

Javascript Convert to base 64 string

```
 function encodeImageUrid(url) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    var imgB = new Image();

    imgB.src = url
    imgB.onload = function () {

        var canvasB = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvasB.width = imgB.width;
        canvasB.height = imgB.height;
        var ctxB = canvasB.getContext('2d');
        ctxB.drawImage(imgB, 0, 0);
        var imgURl = canvasB.toDataURL("image/png").replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");;

        deferred.resolve(imgURl);



    }

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

I loop all hyperlink and convert to base 64 string. Then i push to one list in order to save record

```
  $('.thumbs a[data-name=newImage]').each(function () {
                    encodeImageUrid($(this).attr("href")).done(function (data) {
                        list.push(data);
                    } )

            })
            console.log("Load completed " +list)
```

So nw is my question , every time each function haven loop completed then it directly jump to `console.log("Load completed " +list)`

Anyone got solution? Please help

Comment: need to push all the promises to array and use `$.when` to wait for them all to be resolved before you can access `list`

Comment: can you provide example?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Edit**

Note requirement at original post not appear to include converting actual `img` to `base64` - only `a` `href` string to `base64`.

At below piece each `a` `href` is converted to a `base64` string, then added to `list` `array`, when `list` `length` reaches a `a` `length` `list` is logged to `console`. `window.btoa` [window.btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.btoa) converts `string` to `base64` string.

fwiw, `jquery.Deferred`, `HTML` `canvas` not *needed* to meet requirement at OP - `string` to `base64` - i.e.g.,at

`console.log("Load completed", list)` :

`Load completed    ["aHR0cDovL2kwLmdteC5uZXQvaW1hZ2VzLzI1OC8xODgyMTI1OCxwZD0yLGg9MjUwLG14aD02MDAsbXh3PTgwMCx3PTQ4MC5qcGc=", "aHR0cDovL2Zhcm04LnN0YXRpY2ZsaWNrci5jb20vNzA0Mi82ODk1MjUyNjQ1XzQ1ZjVkZmZmYWFfei5qcGc=", "aHR0cDovL2Zhcm04LnN0YXRpY2ZsaWNrci5jb20vNzE4My82OTQzMjc3NzM3XzIxYjUyMTY1OWNfei5qcGc=", "aHR0cDovL2Zhcm04LnN0YXRpY2ZsaWNrci5jb20vNzA0Ny83MDAwOTUxNDI5XzVlYWUwNzhhNjJfei5qcGc=", "aHR0cDovL2Zhcm02LnN0YXRpY2ZsaWNrci5jb20vNTM0Ni83MDUxNTM3ODk5X2VmYzdhNDQ4MzBfei5qcGc=", "aHR0cDovL2Zhcm04LnN0YXRpY2ZsaWNrci5jb20vNzI2OC82OTUxMTQ4MjYwXzQ0MDY2MWI0ZDFfei5qcGc=", "aHR0cDovL2Zhcm04LnN0YXRpY2ZsaWNrci5jb20vNzI1OS82OTMwMTEyOTg0XzVmY2MwNzYyODhfei5qcGc=", "aHR0cDovL2Zhcm04LnN0YXRpY2ZsaWNrci5jb20vNzI3Ni82ODg2NjI2NzEwXzA0N2NkMDNhY2Jfei5qcGc=", "aHR0cDovL2Zhcm04LnN0YXRpY2ZsaWNrci5jb20vNzAyMC82NjgzMjk5NDkxX2YyYjVmNmFhOGJfei5qcGc="]`

Try

```
$(function () {
    var list = [];
    var imgs = $(".thumbs a[data-name=newImage]");
    var _imgs = imgs.length;
    $(imgs)
    .each(function (i, el) {
        list.push(window.btoa($(el).attr("href")));
        if (list.length === _imgs) {
            console.log("Load completed", list);
        };
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/5p3fM/

Comment: i need to convert to base 64 string. After that push all result to list.